# How can I programmatically pass the current iteration index as input to an ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have the following definition. I want to be able to pass the current iteration number of the map to my ecs task like this `python src.py --my_argument <index>`. I used `"$$.Map.Item.Index"` but it doesn't work. I just runs it literally like this:
`python src.py --my_argument $$.Map.Item.Index`

```json
{
  "Comment": "A state machine that iterates over an array and creates an ECS task for each item.",
  "StartAt": "IterateArray",
  "States": {
    "IterateArray": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "InputPath": "$.arrayField", 
      "ItemsPath": "$", 
      "MaxConcurrency": 0,
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "RunECSTask",
        "States": {
          "RunECSTask": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
              "Cluster": "ClusterName",
              "TaskDefinition": "TaskDefinitionName",
              "Overrides": {
                "ContainerOverrides": [
                  {
                    "Name": "yourContainerName",
                    "Command": [
                      "python",
                      "src.py",
                      "--my_argument",
                      "$$.Map.Item.Index"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }

            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"Command"` with `"Command.$"`.  Appending `.$` to a key tells Step Functions to [interpolate the path references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters-keyvalue) in the value.

See [Passing Data to an Amazon ECS Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html#connect-ecs-pass-to) in the docs for more examples.

Comment: that didn't work for me because I think it was trying to pass the entire content instead of the value of the current iteration so I had to try something else. Can you pls take a look at my follow up question though?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77992087/is-there-a-way-to-pass-the-value-of-a-current-iteration-to-the-next-state-in-sta

Comment: @jamespow OP: _"I want to be able to pass the current iteration number"_.