# Is there a way to pass the value of a current iteration to the next state in state machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, state-machine, aws-step-functions

```
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language for notification on an AWS Fargate task completion",
  "StartAt": "Process",
  "States": {
    "Process": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "InputPath": "$.data",
      "ItemsPath": "$",
      "Parameters": {
        "value.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
      },
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Making",
        "States": {
          "Making": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
              "Cluster": "mycluster",
              "TaskDefinition": "mytaskdefinition",
              "NetworkConfiguration": {
                "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                  "Subnets": [
                  ],
                  "SecurityGroups": [
                  ],
                  "AssignPublicIp": "DISABLED"
                }
              },
              "Overrides": {
                "ContainerOverrides": [
                  {
                    "Name": "my_container",
                    "Command": [
                      "python",
                      "-m",
                      "src"
                    ],
                    "Environment": [
                      {
                        "Name": "FARMER",
                        "Value.$": "$.value.farmer"
                      }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "Next": "Dumping"
          },
          "Dumping": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
              "Cluster": "mycluster",
              "TaskDefinition": "mytaskdefintion",
              "NetworkConfiguration": {
                "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                  "Subnets": [
                  ],
                  "SecurityGroups": [
                  ],
                  "AssignPublicIp": "DISABLED"
                }
              },
              "Overrides": {
                "ContainerOverrides": [
                  {
                    "Name": "my_container",
                    "Command": [
                      "python",
                      "-m",
                      "app"
                    ],
                    "Environment": [
                      {
                        "Name": "FARMER",
                        "Value.$": "$.Overrides.ContainerOverrides[?(@.Name=='my_container')].Environment[0].Value"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Just as I'm passing the value of the current iteration to the first state and setting the environment variable: `"Value.$": "$.value.farmer"`, I want to do the same for the next state `Dumping` as well. I've tried all sorts of things: including `"Value.$": "$.value.farmer"` and `"Value.$": "$.Overrides.ContainerOverrides[?(@.Name=='my_container')].Environment[0].Value"` but they either didn't work at all or didn't work to my satisfaction

`"Value.$": "$.Overrides.ContainerOverrides[?(@.Name=='my_container')].Environment[0].Value"` returned a json instead of a string even though the filtering seems to be correct

Input data looks like this:

```
{

        "data": [
            {"orch": "67e6", "farmer": "mast"},
            {"orch": "67e61b", "farmer": "dono"},
            {"orch": "65d0", "farmer": "pana"}
        ]

    }
```